# UITableViewController's TableView becomes NULL

Tags: iphone, uiview, uitableview

I have  UITableViewController (initiated by the Navigation-based app project template). I am overriding loadView and putting up an alternative view (w/ a UILabel and UIActivityIndicator) to display while the table's contents is loading.

When the loading is done, I remove the loading view and try to display the table view but I see that it's NULL. So in the simulator I see my loading view and then when the loading's done the view disappears but my tableview never comes.

I'm confused what the difference is between self.view and self.tableView in my UITableViewController and how I can exchagn

Comment: are you calling `[super loadView];`?

Comment: Yes. First line of my loadVoew is [super loadView]. If i do nothing else, my UITableView will show up. It's setting self.view to my new UIView (w/ the loading stuff) that seems to trip everything up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably add your subview like this instead `[self.view addSubview:myNewView];`. Then, you can remove it after loading. I am pretty sure that a UITVC's `view` and `tableView` properties are set to the same backing ivar, so you shouldn't mess with them.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense and helped me getting what I wanted working. Thank you!